# Do UPDATE statement performance affect indexed column(s) in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table which is having millions of rows. While doing update I'm using primary key column in `WHERE` clause and it uses index scan as per the `EXPLAIN` plan (within `BEGIN`and `ROLLBACK` block). I have tried to update in both cases (with and without indexed columns in update query), however there is not much change in query `cost`.

```
UPDATE mytable set COL1='test', IDXED_COL1=123, COL2='test', IDXED_COL2=2343
WHERE ID=1 //ID is primary key (using btree index)
```

And

```
UPDATE mytable set COL1='test', COL2='test'
WHERE ID=1 //ID is primary key (using btree index)
```

Is there no impact if the Table and the indexes are huge?

Edit 1

```
#EXPLAIN UPDATE MyTable set C2='Test', C3=1, IdxdC1 = 1, C4='Test', IdxdC2 = 2 WHERE ID = 1234 AND C1=1

 Update on "MyTable"  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=798)
   -> Index Scan using "MyTable_ID_PK" on "MyTable"  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=798)
         Index Cond: ("ID" = '1234'::numeric)
         Filter: ("C1" = '1'::numeric)

#EXPLAIN UPDATE MyTable set C2='Test', C3=1, C4='Test' WHERE ID = 1234 IdxdC1 = 1 AND IdxdC2 = 2 AND C1=1

 Update on "MyTable"  (cost=0.43..8.46 rows=1 width=773)
   ->  Index Scan using "MyTable_ID_PK" on "MyTable"  (cost=0.43..8.46 rows=1 width=773)
         Index Cond: ("ID" = '1234'::numeric)
         Filter: (("IdxdC1" = '1'::numeric) AND ("IdxdC2" = '2'::numeric) AND ("C1" = '1'::numeric))
```

(Both UPDATE's `WHERE` clause are does same in my situation)

Comment: Please share the query plans, without them it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @dezso I have added the ```EXPLAIN``` plan

Comment: Well, I thought you were talking about `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, because you mentioned `BEGIN;` and `ROLLBACK;`.  With simple `EXPLAIN` the query doesn't get executed, only a plan is generated.  That aside, could you please share the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output instead?  It will still not explicitly show the change on the index(es) you mention, but the timing should be at least slightly different.

Comment: @dezso, yeah you are right. I didn't think about it. I could see the execution time significantly improved while removing them from update statement and adding into ```WHERE``` clause.